# Why are my CSS/JS resources loading with HTTPS?

Tags: apache, http, https, wamp

All my page resources - css/js/images- are failing to load. I'm using relative links (e.g. `<link href="includes/css/athletics.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`), and when I inspect the network tab in firebug it shows that all the resource GET requests are HTTPS, even though the main page request is an HTTP request. What would be causing this?

I'm running on a WAMPServer with some alias directories set up.

Comment: do you have a `<base ... >` defined?

Comment: Oh man- was right in the source, I'm just dumb- Please make an answer so I can give you cred...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you have a `<base ... >` defined?